# Gettext() Android Studio from any app screen

Tags: android

I would like to get text from any running app and save it as a txt file. Just wondering if there's any solution to this or sample script. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your string to text file in the following way:
Here, txtmsg is the edittext from which you will retrive the text to write in text file and you can use this block as per your requirement in onCreate() or clicklistner of any view.

```
try {
        FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("mytextfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);
        outputWriter.write(textmsg.getText().toString());
        outputWriter.close();

        //display file saved message
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how to capture screen text on active app? Apart from OCR approach.

Comment: This may help you: http://www.truiton.com/2016/11/optical-character-recognition-android-ocr/. Please accept my answer if it was useful to you.

Comment: My previous question is apart from or other than OCR approach. Hopefully you have an idea for this to get screen texts of a foreground application.